# How to extend default NextJS Router with custom query params with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I would like to extend the default NextRoute (with TypeScript) where I can set the custom query for router.push method.
Something like this:

```
interface QueryProps {
   quantity?: number;
   item?: "apple" | "android";
}
```

Where I get warning/error from TypeScript that product can't be set to 'macbook'. (same goes for quantity if I put string for example)

```
...
const router = useRouter();
...
router.push({
   pathname: '/some-route',
   query: {
      quantity: 5,
      product: "macbook",
   }
})
```

Comment: Please [edit] your title so that it's not a series of tags, but rather summarizes the question. See [ask] for tips on how to do that.